# Customize sharex tick label

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My plot contains 13 x 4 subplots. x-labels are shared. So, only the bottom row that has x-tick labels, which is what I want. The `df` uses `datetime` index.

Now, I want to rotate the x-tick labels. But, my code works on the last subplot only.

Here is the code:

```
x = df.index
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=13, ncols=4, sharex=True, sharey=False, figsize=(20, 35))

axs[0, 0].plot(x, df['y1'])
axs[0, 1].plot(x, df['y2'])
.
.
.
axs[12, 3].plot(x, df['y52'])

plt.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to loop over the last row and then individually rotate the tick labels. You can access the last row of subplots as `axs[-1, :]`. I am showing a sample answer for a smaller number of figures

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, sharex=True, sharey=False, figsize=(8, 5))

axs[0, 0].plot([1,2,3])
axs[0, 1].plot([1,2,3])
axs[2, 3].plot([1,2,3])

for ax in axs[-1, :]:
    ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=45)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]